# register_my_menus() redeclared causing fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I am creating a new wordpress theme and for menus using:

```
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array( 'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ) )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

This generates a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare register_my_menus() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\myTheme\functions.php:5) in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\myTheme\functions.php on line 9
```

This doesn't get called/used anywhere else.

My understanding is that the function is called `register_my_menus()` and then the menu is added initialized with the add_function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried changing the name of the function? It is best to add some prefix to all of your custom functions, in order to avoid such an errors.
For example, try using:

```
function theme_name_register_my_menus(){
register_nav_menus(
    array( 'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ) )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'theme_name_register_my_menus' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing register_nav_menus() inside a function, try this:

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'header_menu' => 'Header Menu',
    )
);
```

Just add the code above to your **functions.php** file.